# Restoring filesystem on external disk not working

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

I'm using fsck to try to recover the filesystem of an external HDD. I'm getting the follwing error with no more information.

```
$ sudo fsck_hfs -l /dev/disk2
** /dev/rdisk2 (NO WRITE)
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-582.40.4).
VolumeObjectIsValid: Cannot GetVolumeBlock: 6
```

I'm thinking is a phisical problem, disk looks good tought.

From disk utility I´m not able to initialize the disk, but at least is being recognized by the OSX.

Any idea on this?

Comment: That looks like a read error “Cannot GetVolumeBlock”.  You might have a drive that’s failing.

Comment: Yes, do you think is there anyway I can solve it with software? The disk util recognize it

`/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *0 B        disk2`

Comment: I don’t believe you can.  A failure like this can be one of three things:  a defect on the platter, a failing head, or a failure of the controller chip (electronics).  It seems the drive is getting a read command but it is either not responding or getting back garbage.  Software can’t overcome that.

Comment: Thanks for your time